# access denied while accessing a sharepoint 2013 list over http using rest

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013

I was trying to access a sharepoint 2013 list using REST over HTTPS

I used the following Syntax

https://name.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName/_api/web/lists

But it respond with a error that says **Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource**

Should i give permission somewhere?what might be wrong with the request?

Answer (score 1):

In the future post this on sharepoint.stackexchange.com bud you will get a faster answer, I only saw this by accident on a google query.

Basically this is by design, it isn't about giving permission only pre authorised accounts will get direct access without authentication and then it is security trimmed after that.

Otherwise you need to authenticate against the api with OAUTH.

The rest api being a massive subject that I cannot possibly cover here I recommend you google:

"using oauth sharepoint rest api"

Some good links are:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/jj164022.aspx
http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/01/calling-sharepoint-search-using-rest-eg.html

Good luck matey.